# Websites that started using Rails or Django but switched to "enterprise" solutions?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, django

Out of curiosity, I'd like to know if anyone knows of any somewhat large website that started out using Django, Ruby on Rails, or similar frameworks, but later switched to using something more "enterprise-ish" such as .NET or JSP.

(I tried searching for this question, but couldn't find any.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter started out as a pure ruby on rails application iirc but later moved their backend to a system written in Scala running on a JVM

[More Info](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/twitter_on_scala.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Curse](http://www.curse.com/) switched from Django to ASP.NET. Reasons are unknown but it was around the time of the acquisition so likely to match the buyers technology.

Comment: Oops. Didn't notice Dominic Rodgers comment about curse. Just for clarification though, its 600k visits per day not unique users. Similar but not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe curse.com moved from Django to ASP.NET (see the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886221/does-django-scale/886645#886645)). curse.com is *somewhat large*, see [quantcast's stats](http://www.quantcast.com/curse.com). Daily traffic currently at 600k unique users.