# Django web service: fast enough?

Tags: python, django, web-services, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Django Scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886221/does-django-scale)

I'm interested in using Django to put together a web site, but an important component of that web site will be an API that I expose through web services.  Although there won't be many hits on the server initially, let's pretend that they will start rolling in faster and faster.  Does Django scale well, or at some point will I soon have to replace the Django web service with something more heavy duty?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886221/does-django-scale

Comment: See the KeyNote at DjangoCon 2008 by Cal Henderson (from Flick) for specific scalability tools that are not part of Django. The rest mostly depends on your actual implementation. Most of what makes a website fast is *not* the server-side scripts. Specifically: cache, cache, cache. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6Fr65PFqfk

Comment: @John Berryman: the question will be closed soon enough, I've added a close vote already :)
You might also be interested in this talk: http://djangocon.blip.tv/file/4112452/

Comment: @John: I've closed the question, but it might still be useful to anyone who searches with keywords that match your title/content better than the original.  We normally leave questions like these here to serve as a link to the original.

Comment: @Bill thank you, I've been wondering what the proper etiquette is

Comment: @WoLpH - I watched a couple of minutes of that and it looked interesting. Thanks.