# Does Django Scale (2012)?

Tags: python, mysql, django, web-applications

The answers to this question -- [Does Django scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886221/651174) -- which asks the same, are about 2.5 years out of date. I'm hoping this would make for a nice discussion / potential wiki about the subject and relevant links around it.

Comment: Hi David, StackOverflow is not the place for discussions. StackOverflow is a Q&A site for objective questions about a specific programming problem you're facing. While this is a great question and topic, it just doesn't fit the goal of this site. Good luck!

Comment: This question can not be answered with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question will be - yes and no.

Scalability of a web application purely depends on implementation and your requirements. If done correctly (requirements suites Django) then,

1. Django scales horizontally pretty well.
2. Every thing scales Vertically, Django is no exception.

For more guidelines about scaling large scale,

1. how Disqus does it -> http://blog.disqus.com/post/1083759994/scaling-disqus
2. Pownce -> http://www.slideshare.net/mmalone/scaling-django-1393282

And please next time do your homework before asking here.