# Scalability of a django app in 2014?

Tags: python, django, apache, web-applications, scalability

This is more an update to this thread: [Does Django scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886221/does-django-scale)

Since it's not very clear and seemingly a popular question that people want to know, let's say I have an idea for an app, and I have a potential user-base that would be interacting more or less in a real-time fashion with my site/app. I'd expect if it got popular that I'd need to handle ~100,000 concurrent users.

So, to more or less update the other thread...

- Could Django/Apache/mod_wsgi handle something like this *if* configured and optimized correctly? Not 100,000 users per day, but per second?
- Could something like this be hosted in EC2? What kind of instances would you use? What infrastructures are best suited to something like this now?
- What type of polling mechanism would you implement?
- What is the best scalable stack, Apache/mod_wsgi? nginx? Twisted? Comet? Websockets?

Comment: Worry about that when you get there. Also, yes. Examples: Instagram and Pinterest and see: http://highscalability.com/

Comment: While this might not be on-topic, I'm not sure that there is a better place to ask it.