# Django mezzanine vs Wordpress

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm working on a project which will use python to collect data and display it in a blog like way.

I'm already familiar with Wordpress, my solution to import these data would be to manually edit SQL wordpress database with python and update the values of the single post according to my data.

I not very familiar with python and Django but i saw that Mezzanine is a sort of Wordpress for Django.

Would be easier or faster the data exchange between my Python script and a Mezzanine app or it's the same as between Python and SQL? I'd like to know also about performances.

Comment: Mezzanine has a built-in support for migrating from WordPress. http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/blog-importing.html

Comment: You'll find some information about performance of Django in the thread [Does Django scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886221/does-django-scale). Django powers some very high traffic sites, such as instagram, disqus and pinterest.

Comment: Thanks, though i don't have already a wordpress blog, i'm planning to have some data to organize in a way that resembles a blog.

Comment: Generally you don't need to write SQL when you work with django, only native Python. Django has tools for inspeciting an existing database and then generate python code that models that legacy database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Thanks that's what i was searching! You can put it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't need to write SQL when you work with Django, only native Python. Django has tools for inspecting an existing database and then generate python code that models that legacy database. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/