# Django Rest Framework in production to take 500 parallel requests

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, webserver, amazon-ecs

I have a current flask api which is running in 'development' server and doesn't take 500 concurrent requests(it hangs)

I created a flask webserver using nginx and gunicorn to take multiple requests but I need to create a solution using Django REST Framework and I have heard that Django REST Framework doesn't need a web server(nginx and gunicorn) to run concurrent requests(around 500) and handles everything on its own.

So I am looking for a api solution using below mentioned tools/conditions:
1. Django REST Framework
2. Docker/ECS deployment
3. can take 500 concurrent requests

Any feedback will be helpful

Comment: see this, [**Does Django scale?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886221/does-django-scale)

Comment: You should always use nginx and gunicorn (or any similar alternative) when putting your web app in production. Only time you don't have to use them is during development.